# asp htaccess 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis, asp-classic

I'm trying to redirect 3 pages but for some reason, it doens't seem to work. Site is built with asp

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Make sure directory listing is disabled
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on

    # Re-write for PDFs requests not pre-pended with /pdf/ I.E. in the root - prepend /pdf/ - Use negative look-ahead - If the file doesn't exist you get a 500 though sadly.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?!pdf/)(.*)\.(pdf)$
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pdf/$1 -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pdf/$1 [L]

    # If the URI is not in /images,/pdf,/css, or /js let the handler process it
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/images/|/pdf/|/css/|/js/)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !handler.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ handler.php/$1 [L]

    # If the URI IS in the above directories but the file doesn't exist run it through the handler as well
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/images/|/pdf/|/css/|/js/)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ handler.php/$1 [L]

    # Permanent URL redirect
    Redirect 301 /Server_Rack_Cabinet_RS_42U.asp http://www.rackmountsolutions.net/cruxial-core-1000-series-server-rack.asp
    Redirect 301 /Sound_Dampening_Proof_Server_Rack.asp http://www.rackmountsolutions.net/AcoustiQuiet_Soundproof_Server_Rack.asp
    Redirect 301 /Relay_Rack_4_post.asp http://www.rackmountsolutions.net/4_Post_Server_Rack.asp

</IfModule>
```

The # Permanent URL redirect portion doesn't seem to work. The above is the entire code I have in the .htaccess file.

Comment: `Redirect` directive is provided by `mod_alias`: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this site is running on an IIS server, there was a **web.config** file overruling the .htaccess file somehow. See the  to see how i did it. The **web.config** file was in my site's root folder.

```
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
    <rules>

      <rule name="Env-leader-redirect1" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^Server_Rack_Cabinet_RS_42U.asp" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.rackmountsolutions\.net$" />
        </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.rackmountsolutions.net/cruxial-core-1000-series-server-rack.asp" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Env-leader-redirect2" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^Server_Rack_Cabinet_RS_42U.asp" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.rackmountsolutions\.net$" />
        </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.rackmountsolutions.net/cruxial-core-1000-series-server-rack.asp" />
    </rule>

    </rules>
  </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```